# Nginx GeoIP variables not working under reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, proxy

I have a setup composed of two web apps running on apache and node js but all being served through an nginx server acting as a pure reverse proxy.

This way I have some urls to go to one app and some urls going to another one and that works fine. However my website has to restrict access from outside US.

I need that nginx detects my country and if it's anything other than US redirect to a /restricted page but if it's a valid US ip address it should go to the website.

I followed the tutorials here https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-use-geoip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16.04/

I found that the module is loaded when I type:

```
# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.12.1
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads
```

I can see it says: **--with-http_geoip_module**

I modified my **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** file and added the geoip database file as follows:

```
 http {
   # Geo IP
   geoip_country /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat; # the country IP database

   map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
      default no;
      US yes;
   }
   # Other stuff #
 }
```

And inside my virtual hosts I added the geoip header so I could read it for debugging purposes or make the redirection using the $allowed_country variable as follows:

```
server {
     if ($allowed_country = no) {
       return 301 https://127.0.0.1:8001/restricted;
     }

     location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;

       fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
     }
}
```

However my **$allowed_country** is always = no. When I disable that and debug the content of the **GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE** **header in my nodejs app the header is never set (as if the $geoip_country_code was blank)** but if I replace the **$geoip_country_code** variable for something else I can totally see the custom header in my Node application.

I have tried the nginx versions shipped with Ubuntu 16.04,Ubuntu 14.04 and I compiled by hand to make sure the module is enabled and installed without success, no matter what I do the **$geoip_country_code** is always blank or not set.

**/var/log/syslog** is not showing any errors in my startup sequence for nginx, in fact if I put a wrong file to be read by the geoip module you get an error so I know the file is not corrupted and it's being loaded.

I've googled extensively before posting this question and found similar questions but after having tried everything suggested nothing seems to work for me.

The reason why this is a problem and I cannot make the country detection inside Node is because I'm using the proxy_cache from nginx to cache requests on the public site but if I do that without detecting the country then everybody get access to the page and not only the US people as soon as somebody from the US renders the website.

Hope anybody can give me a hand with this.

Comment: Is there a possibility that "proxy_set_header" should be set inside "http" block and not inside "location" block?